# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net, fetch-api

I am having problem why my code is not working on any other method besides get. I've tried putting random things on API but it kept on changing to status code 405 or 404 or now 500. I don't know what is wrong but I'm pretty sure its on the API. Please help.

Here is my code on get:

```
  componentDidMount() {
  fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/getemployeedetails/')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json()})
  .then((json) => {
    this.setState({jsonReturnedValue : json});
  });
}
```

and this is my code for delete however it wont work (it says fetch error )

```
deleteEmployee(id) {
 
   jQuery.support.cors = true;
    debugger
      fetch ('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/DeleteEmployeeDetail/'+ id,
      { method: 'DELETE',
        credentials: 'same-origin'})
      .then( 
          res =>  {
              this.setState({jsonReturnedValue : json})
              var employee = [...this.state.employee];
              var idx = employee.findIndex(item => item.Employee_ID === id);
              employee.splice(idx, 1);
              this.setState({employee})

         }
      )
      .catch( err => console.error(err))
  }
```

here is the code for the button for the delete

```
<td><center><button className ="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.deleteEmployee.bind(this,  d.Employee_ID)}>Delete</button></center></td>
```

Here is my code for the API web config:

```
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  <add name="ReactJsx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" path="*.jsx" type="React.Web.JsxHandlerFactory, React.Web" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
```

Comment: I think this is a server issue. A pre-flight response usually only returns the valid response if it can be served for the host in question.

Comment: @Panther Im confuse what do you mean?

Comment: As you mentioned pre-flight request has status 500. The status is set by the server. So you have to check your server code, but based on the description in the question you are looking at frontend for solution.